# Why does "xdg-open" fail although "xdg-mime query defaut " succeeds on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 10.10, `xdg-open` fails to open the file and give me the error:

> No application is registered as handling this file

But `xdg-mime query defaut ...` succeeds for the mime type. Why?

Here is my process:

1. Added a new mime type `application/vnd.xx` by `xdg-mime install mytype.xml`. Then `xdg-mime query filetype <file name>` shows that the new mime type is recognized.
2. I wrote my desktop entry file "my-app.desktop" like this:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=xxx
   Comment=xxx
   Icon=
   Exec=/usr/bin/my-app %U
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Utility;
   MimeType=application/vnd.xx;
   ```
3. I copied this desktop file to `~/Desktop`. After I re-login, I saw the shortcut on the desktop and `xdg-mime query defualt application/vnd.xx` printed out this desktop file.
4. But, `xdg-open <file name>` fails with the error:

   > No application is registered as handling this file

I've installed nautilus. Do I miss something? How do I fix this?

Comment: I only copied my program "my-app" to /usr/bin. Is it enough? Or I still need some *install* operation. Nautilus also shows no application selected for the mime type ;-(

Comment: I reformatted your post; if you need to make further changes, you can just [edit this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/9053/edit) instead of posting a new question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know off the top of my head if this is the cause of your problem, but in general application `*.desktop` files need to be in specific places to be fully recognized.  Try moving your `my-app.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/my-app.desktop` (create that directory first if needed:  `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications`).  If you used a full pathname to the `*.desktop` file, change it to just the basename; I don't think pathnames work as expected there.

Comment: Great thanks for your suggestion! I moved the my-app.destop to /usr/share/applications. Then it works!

Comment: @Amanda if you find the answer works then please mark it as "accepted", that would help others when they have the same question.

Comment: How can I mark it as "accepted"? I didn't find a link to follow .Thanks!

Comment: Per the FAQ (link at top and bottom):  When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)