# why “xdg-open” fails although “xdg-mime query defaut ” succeeds on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does “xdg-open” fail although “xdg-mime query defaut ” succeeds on Ubuntu 10.10?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9053/why-does-xdg-open-fail-although-xdg-mime-query-defaut-succeeds-on-ubuntu-10)

(Sorry to post the question again for text format reason)

On Ubuntu 10.10, "xdg-open" fails to open the file and give me an error ""No application is registered as handling this file" error ". But "xdg-mime query defaut ..." succeed for the mime type. Why?

Here is my process: 
1. added a new mime type "application/vnd.xx" by "xdg-mime install mytype.xml" 
   Then "xdg-mime query filetype " shows the the new mime type is recognized.

2.I wrote my desktop entry file "my-app.desktop" like this: 
  [Desktop Entry] Name=xxx 
  Comment=xxx 
  Icon= Exec=/usr/bin/my-app %U 
  Terminal=false 
  Type=Application 
  Categories=Utility; 
  MimeType=application/vnd.xx;

3.I copied this desktop file to ~/Desktop, after I re-login, I saw the shortcut on the desktop and "xdg-mime query defualt application/vnd.xx" print out this desktop file.

4.but, xdg-open fails with the error "No application is registered as handling this file" error"!

I've installed nautilus. Do I miss something? Could anybody share me some idea?
Great thanks! 
Amanda